# Bellman Ford Algorithm fails to compute shortest path for a directed edge-weighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, bellman-ford

I was recently understanding shortest path algorithms when I encountered the problem below in the book [Algorithms, 4th edition, Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/).

> Suppose that we convert an EdgeWeightedGraph into a Directed EdgeWeightedGraph by creating two DirectedEdge objects in the EdgeWeightedDigraph (one in each direction) for each Edge in the EdgeWeightedGraph and then use the Bellman-Ford algorithm. Explain why this approach fails spectacularly.

Below is a piece of my [code](http://ideone.com/p3n9SQ) implementing Bellman Ford Algorithm (queue-based):

```
private void findShortestPath(int src) {
    queue.add(src);
    distTo[src] = 0;
    edgeTo[src] = -1;
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        int v = queue.poll();
        onQueue[v] = false;
        for (Edge e : adj(v)){
            int w = e.dest;
            if (distTo[w] > distTo[v] + e.weight) {
                distTo[w] = distTo[v] + e.weight;
                edgeTo[w] = v;
            }
            if (!onQueue[w]) {
                onQueue[w] = true;
                queue.add(w);
            }

            //Find if a negative cycle exists after every V passes
            if (cost++ % V == 0) {
                if (findNegativeCycle())
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried many examples on paper, but am unable to find scenarios where the directed graph generated would have new negative cycles in them, simply by converting an edge into two edges in opposite directions. I assume that there were no pre-existing negative cycles in the unweighted undirected edge-weighted graph.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is CS theory. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP cross-posted on CS theory.

Comment: @MarcB If the question was phrased as: "I have implementation to working BF on directed graph. Can I use it to find shortest path for undirected graph by duplicating each edge and make it go to both diretions?" This is basically the same question, and it is pretty clear it has a clear programming context and on topic. (Also, given link provides implementations in java)

Comment: @amit: but there's no code, so that'd boil down to asking for opinions, which are ALSO offtopic

Comment: @MarcB From [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in), source code is not mandatory.  `but if your question generally covers…

a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!` (The rephrased variant clearly covers all)

Comment: @MarcB added algo implementation, plus provided a link for the complete code.

Comment: @ShubhamMittal This implementation looks like Dijkstra's algorithm, not BF.

Comment: @amit This is the queue-based implementation (practically better) of bellman ford as explained by Sedgewick. The complete algorithm from his booksite can be obtained at http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/BellmanFordSP.java.html

Comment: @LiorKogan Removed post from cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am not familiar with it, and it seems wrong implementation to me with the counter example of:  `V={a,b,c,d,e} E = {(a,b,1), (b,c,1), (c,d,1), (d,e,1) (a,d,5)}`. It will start with `a`, and add `b,d` to queue and set `w[b]=1,w[d]=5`. Then it will go `b` and do `w[c]=2` and add `c`, then from `d` set `w[e] = 6` and add `e`. Then from `c` set `w[d] = 3` and not re-add `d`, Nothing to do on `e`, and done. But at this point, `w[e] = 6`, which is not the shortest distance. A big hint this solution is wrong is its time complexity, which is `O(|E|)`, since each edge is iterated at most once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121668/discussion-between-shubham-mittal-and-amit).

Answer (score -2):

Your algorithm & code has no problem.It can give the shortest distance in a graph without negative circle.And it's easy to find out negative circle only by a array 'number[i]' record **the number that 'i' is put into the queue.**

It can be proved that if a point is put into the queue for over |P|(points number) times,there is a negative circle in the graph.So you can add:

`number[v]++;
    if (number[v] > |P|) 
        return -1;`

The shortest distance in a graph with negative circle has no meaning.So for most of the situation you just need to print something while finding it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer is nowhere related to the question I've posted. Please follow the guidelines as set in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question while answering.

Comment: sorry, I'm just poor in English...But I think if there is a negative edge in an undirected graph, it is a negative circle.Because the definition of a negative circle is "a road begin&stop in a point with the negative length".I can just go left to right to left ... in the edge, so your algorithm didn't work.If you define that one edge should only be used for less than one time, it has yet another algorithm to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense. You may edit your answer with this point and i'll accept it.